# Dapper : How to load virtual properties?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I want to retrieve an `Advert`

```
public class Advert
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreation { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Creator { get; set; }
}
```

(with the `Creator` property loaded)

```
public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

with the following function :

```
public Advert GetById(int id)
{
    String sql = "select * from Advert inner join Member on Advert.Creator = Member.ID where Advert.ID = @aid";
    return unitOfWork.Connection.Query<Advert,Member,Advert>(sql, (advert, member) => { advert.Creator = member; return advert; } , new { aid=id}).Single();
}
```

But I have the following error :

> InvalidCastException: unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to 'Models.Member'.

What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: From this little code it´s impossiböe to guess where your error is. I can´t seen any `int` where a `Models.Member` is requrired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the query it looks like the `Advert.Creator` column, which appears to be of type `int`, is conflicting with the `Member Creator` property on the model.

Change the name of the property to something else to avoid the name conflict

```
public class Advert {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreation { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Owner { get; set; }
}
```

And update the query accordingly

```
public Advert GetById(int id) {
    var connection = unitOfWork.Connection;
    String sql = 
    @"select * from Advert AS A
    inner join Member AS M on A.Creator = M.ID 
    where A.ID = @aid";
    var data connection.Query<Advert, Member, Advert>(
        sql, 
        (advert, member) => { advert.Owner = member; return advert; }, 
        new { aid = id }
    );
    return data.Single();
}
```

Ideally the `Advert.Creator` column in the table should have been name `CreatorId`. This would have allowed the original code to work as desired.